# Netty client multiple requests

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server, netty

First, I'll explain the situation and the logic that I'm trying to implement:

- I have multiple threads, each put result of it work, some object called `Result` into queue `QueueToSend`
- My `NettyClient` runs in thread and takes `Result` from `QueueToSend` every 1 milisecond and should connect to server and send a message, that is created from `Result`. 
  I also need this connections to be asynch. So I need the `Result` list to be known by `NettyHandler` to send right message and process right result and then again send response.

So I initialize `NettyClient` bootstrap

```
bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(
                new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(
                        Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                        Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));
```

and sets pipeline once when app starts.
Then, every milisecond I take `Result` object from `QueueToSend` and connect to server

```
ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host,port);
ResultConcurrentHashMap.put(future.getChannel().getId(), result);
```

I decided to use static `ConcurrentHashMap` to save every result object taken from `QueueToSend` assosiated with channel.

The first problem takes place in `NettyHandler` in method channelConnected, when I am trying to take `Result` object assosiated with channel from `ResultConcurrentHashMap`.

```
@Override
public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) {
       Channel channel = ctx.getPipeline.getChannel();
       Result result = ResultConcurrentHashMap.get(channel.getId());
}
```

But sometimes `result` is null (1 of 50), even thought it should be in `ResultConcurrentHashMap`. I think it happens cause that `channelConnected` event happens before `NettyClient` runs this code:

```
ResultConcurrentHashMap.put(future.getChannel().getId(), result);
```

May be it will not appear if I run `NettyServer` and `NettyClient` not on localhost both, but remotely, it will take moretime to estabilish the connection. But I need a solution for this issue.

**Another issue** is that I am sending messages every 1 milisecond asynchromously and I suppose that messages are may be mixed and server can not read them properly. If I run them one by one it will be ok :

```
future.getChannel().getCloseFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();
```

But I need asynchromus sending, and process right results, assosiated with channel and send responses. 
What should I implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ChannelFutures are executed asynchronously before the events get fired. For example channel connect future will be completed before firing the channel connected event.

So you have to register a channel future listener after calling bootstrap.connect() and write your code in the listener to initialize the HashMap, then it will be visible to the handler.

```
        ChannelFuture channelFuture = bootstrap.connect(remoteAddress, localAddress);

        channelFuture.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                resultConcurrentHashMap.put(future.getChannel().getId(), result);
            }
        });
```

Comment: My NettyClient takes result object from queue every 1 milisec, so the result object changes in netty client every 1 milisec, if cannel connection will appear in 2 milisec, I will have another result object assosiated with this channel? Or not?

Comment: I guess, you have to interchange data between threads (result producer, Netty client) using a blocking queue, not a hashmap. After calling bootstrap.connect(), create a BlockingQueue as a channel local. the handler can lookup for the queue when client its ready to send and poll the queue for every 1 ms. from result producer, just offer the data.No data will be lost because of delayed netty client start.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But it will not work in my case. I have big amount of result produser and need to keep asynchronous channels sending, reciving messages as much as i can. Now i am 90% ready to say that frame mixing is server problem. Your first answer helped of to solve first problem so i accept your answer. thanks